# Why when uploading a video file to youtube and on the website of youtube.com the file rejected on my program it's not showing rejection message?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, google-api, youtube-api

This is my upload method i'm using to upload to youtube:

```
private void UploadVideo(string FileName, string VideoTitle, string VideoDescription)
{
    try
    {
        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
        });

        video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
        video.Snippet.Title = VideoTitle;
        video.Snippet.Description = VideoDescription;
        video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
        video.Status = new VideoStatus();
        video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public";
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            const int KB = 0x400;
            var minimumChunkSize = 256 * KB;

            var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video,
                        "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
            videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged +=
                        videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
            videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived +=
                        videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;
            // The default chunk size is 10MB, here will use 1MB.
            videosInsertRequest.ChunkSize = minimumChunkSize * 3;
            dt = DateTime.Now;
            totalBytes = fileStream.Length;
            videosInsertRequest.Upload();
            //videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception errors)
    {
        string errorss = errors.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then I have the event `videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived`:

```
private void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video obj)
{
    uploadstatus = obj.Status.UploadStatus;
}
```

uploadstatus is string.

The problem is when I'm uploading a file that is duplicated I see on [youtube.com](http://youtube.com) that the file was rejected since it's duplicated.

But in my program on uploadstatus I see "uploaded"
And I should see "rejected" or something like that.

There is a property of the obj RejectionReason but when i'm doing:

```
uploadstatus = obj.Status.RejectionReason;
```

`uploadstatus` is null but again on the website of youtube I see the message that upload rejected since duplicated.

On the `RejectionReason` property decription it say:

This property is only present if the uploadStatus property indicates that the upload was rejected.
But obj.Status.UploadStatus state is "uploaded"

I'm using the google api v3.0

Comment: Do you still see the same status? It may take some time for the servers to update the status of the upload.